# Exclude directory from IntelliSense (only)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a generic way to prevent a given set of files from being parsed by IntelliSense modules while it still shows up elsewhere?

For instance, I have a third-party library that provides an `AppModel` class I can customise. Such class is defined in several places:

1. The library bundles a template to copy from.
2. The library includes a usage example.
3. The library implements the class in a helper tool.
4. The library defines the class for its test harness.
5. I implement the class in my app.

My implementation is the only one that gets loaded when the app runs and the only one I care about when I navigate my code or use *Go to Symbol* yet I need to pick among the 5 definitions every time.

For languages where there isn't a specific setting, the only way to go appears to be `files.exclude`. But that directive basically makes the file or directory completely disappear from the program. It won't even show up in the *Explorer* pane. That feature seems designed for source control metadata and similar stuff and I don't think it's entirely convenient for third-party libraries.

Any idea?